# Unhandled Rejection Type Error from API fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I got a weird error while working on my Spotify Web Application. I try to save a playlist to my account, which has to fetch the `id` element from the https://api.spotify.com/v1/me endpoint, then apply the playlist to your account. Everything seems fine otherwise, besided the fetch to that endpoint, which throws the error:

`Spotify.js:81 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)'`

I've never seen this error before, and am not sure why it's happening. The `findUserId` method is:

```
findUserId() {
  if(accessToken === undefined) {
    this.getAccessToken();
  }
  console.log(accessToken);
  let userId;
  fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {headers: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
    ).then(response => {return response.json()}
    ).then(jsonResponse => {
        userId = jsonResponse.id;
    });
  console.log(userId);
  return userId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to set the `Authentication` header inside `headers`. Also, `fetch` is async, which means that you try to log `userId` before the network request has finished. To fix that, put your log inside the second `then` callback and return the `fetch`:

```babel
findUserId() {
  if (accessToken === undefined) {
    this.getAccessToken();
  }

  console.log(accessToken);

  return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {
    headers: { Authentication: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonResponse => {
      userId = jsonResponse.id;
      console.log(userId);
      return userId;
    });
}
```

Then you can use `findUserId` like this:

```
async otherFunction() {
  const userId = await this.findUserId();
  console.log(userId);
}
```

or like this:

```
otherFunction() {
  this.findUserId().then(userId => console.log(userId));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`headers` should be an object - change

```
{headers: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
```

to

```
{headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`}}
```

Comment: This fixes the error, but it still returns userId as undefined

Comment: what's the value of `jsonResponse`?

Comment: `"display_name: "Beau Russell"
external_urls: {spotify: "https://open.spotify.com/user/yourknightmares"}
followers: {href: null, total: 3}
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/yourknightmares"
id: "yourknightmares"
images: [{…}]
type :"user"
uri: "spotify:user:yourknightmares"`

Comment: oh yes, you're dealing with asynchronicity here. You see, `findUserId ` returns before the fetch is even executed. It should be a promise, like so: https://pastebin.com/YeAnhu9z

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do headers with fetch.  I think you mean to set the authorization header.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

edit: wrong link